# Python ssh client over socks (proxy)

Tags: python, ssh, twisted, socks, paramiko

So, I need to connect to SSH server through proxy socks.
I read paramiko and twisted.conch docs, but didn`t found proxy socks support there.

Answer (score 4):

This socket-wrapper allows you to use static ssh-tunnels. I found a common solution for my problem:

1. Use paramiko `SSHClient` class
2. Extend `SSHClient` with your own class
3. Re-implement the `connect()` method: 
   Instead of using a standard socket object we pass to it a fixed proxied socket from the python package `sockipy`

Answer (score 2):

[Paraproxy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/paraproxy) (a Paramiko addon for SSH2 ProxyCommands) looks like it can do it.  There's no documentation online but in downloading the source and inspecting the `README` file, I found this:

> Paraproxy is a supplement to the great
>   "paramiko" SSH2 module. While paramiko
>   has a really good support for SSH(2)
>   it lacks the ProxyCommand feature.
>
> ProxyCommands can be used e.g. to
>   connect to VPN tunnels but they
>   provide manny other nice features.
>
> Paraproxy, once imported will hook
>   into the SSHClient class provided by
>   paramiko which in turn gains full
>   support for SSH ProxyCommands.
>
> No changes to existing code are
>   needed.

Give that a shot!