# Dynamic application-level port forwarding with SOCKS using paramiko library in python

Tags: python, ssh, putty, paramiko, socks

I'm trying to connect to SSH server in the following way:

```
import paramiko
import socks
sock = socks.socksocket()
sock.setproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, 'localhost', 22, True)
sock.connect((**IP address of SSH server**, 22))
t = paramiko.Transport(sock)
t.connect( None, 'username', 'password')
```

And get the following error

```
> Traceback (most recent call last): ...
>     sock.connect((**IP address of SSH server**, 22))   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 368, in connect
>     _orgsocket.connect(self,(self.__proxy[1],portnum))   File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
>     return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args) socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machi ne actively
> refused it
```

My goal is to simulate Putty's way in creating SSH SOCKS Proxy as here:
[Configure PuTTY To Create SSH SOCKS Proxy For Secure Browsing](http://vectrosecurity.com/content/view/67/26/).
Or equivalent

> ssh -D [localhost]port

for local dynamic application-level port forwarding.

Can someone explain, please, what's wrong and how to do it the right way using paramiko?
Thanks.

P.S.
I've found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5823383/1264304 However, I don't succeed to implement it.  Someone?

Comment: Can someone help me? Putty connects to server, however paramiko doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paramiko can natively connect to ssh. You don't need the SOCKS library to connect to the ssh server. Additionally, when you try, the remote server refuses to connect because you don't authenticate.

The proper way to do this would be to connect with paramiko's [sshClient](http://docs.paramiko.org/paramiko.SSHClient-class.html):

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect('yourServer', username='you', 
    password='yay!')
```

And then, get the underlying [transport](http://docs.paramiko.org/paramiko.Transport-class.html):

```
trans = ssh.get_transport()
```

Finally, have the ssh client forward a tcp port with [open channel](http://docs.paramiko.org/paramiko.Transport-class.html#open_channel):

```
trans.open_channel("forwarded-tcpip", dest_addr=('serverIP',8000), src_addr=('localhost'),8000))
```

This will cause any connections on port 8000 locally to be forwarded to port 8000 remotely across this ssh session.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. I tried your code with a little change **dest_adrr = (IP, port)** and **src_addr = (IP, port)**, while still getting and exception:     `chan = trans.open_channel('forwarded-tcpip', dest_addr = ('132.72.80.162', 2
2), src_addr = ('localhost', 22))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 773, in open_
channel
    raise e
paramiko.ChannelException: Administratively prohibited`

Comment: @user1264304 You may need to call the `request_port_forward` first. Or, your server may not allow port forwarding of whatever port you have selected. Or any ports at all.

Comment: @ Spencer Rathbun I guess you're right. I've added the call request_port_forward(serverIP, 22) and got the **paramiko.SSHException: TCP forwarding request denied**, however, Putty's port forwarding is working with the same server. Not clear why.

Comment: I've seen `Administratively prohibited` when I use paramiko to connect and there's a manual prompt (e.g. prompt to rotate unix user's password) which paramiko can't handle well.